# How can I convert input text on HTML to individual box-like structures each time user types a word separated by comma (see picture)

Tags: html, css, angular

[image]

I would like to know how I can convert text data into individual boxes as shown in the picture each time user enters a word separated after a comma (I am currently creating this as an input field on Angular)

Comment: you may check this [https://github.com/yairEO/tagify](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify). Will help in creating tags inside input filed.

Comment: Or check this lib for angular [https://github.com/Brakebein/ngx-tagify](https://github.com/Brakebein/ngx-tagify)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a variable with ngModel and a `*ngFor` over this variable.split(',')

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name">
<ng-container *ngIf="name">
  <div *ngFor="let item of name.split(',')">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

NOTE: You can use mat-chip-list in the way

```
<mat-chip-list *ngIf="name">
  <mat-chip
    *ngFor="let item of name.split(',');let i=index">
    {{ item }} 
    <button matChipRemove>
    <mat-icon (click)="remove(i)">cancel</mat-icon>
  </button>
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

where

```
  remove(index:number)
  {
    const list=this.name.split(",") //get the list
    list.splice(index,1)       //remove the element at position "index"
    this.name=list.length?list.join(','):null  //give value to name using join
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jwmj3f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

NOTE: If you only need the "list" based in a variable just give value to the variable

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for something like Angular Material Chips.
https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples